# Understanding Web 8.5 Deployer configuration and Worker/deployment process

Tags: web8.5, configuration, deployer

I'm interested in the following (similarities and differences between the old and the new architecture). Some are out of pure curiosity, whilst others I need because of some business requirements:

1. Is this correct: the pipelines are executed top to bottom and if the current publish action (publish/unbpublish) does not match a given `Pipeline`'s `Action` it is skipped?
2. Can a `Step` contain multiple Modules?
3. What is the role of the `Steps` node, just a container element?
4. Why is the Processor entity removed, and what is its new "counterpart", what fulfils the same role? Am I right in guessing that this was removed because of the new architecture and the plans for merging the Docs publishing?
5. The [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-DA883F20-294E-4D96-BBDA-1EBDB1C42DBB&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-DA883F20-294E-4D96-BBDA-1EBDB1C42DBB.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-DA883F20-294E-4D96-BBDA-1EBDB1C42DBB)  for extending the Content Deployer only mentions Modules whilst earlier Processors could also be customized. Is the counterpart entity not extensible or is it again a "semi-public" -* extension point?
6. The reference section in the online [docs](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-3BAC093F-B45D-4C72-8195-A54BC39284B6&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-38E53443-EAB5-4943-84B4-195940D49404.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-3BAC093F-B45D-4C72-8195-A54BC39284B6)) mentiones only 3 of the possibilities for the `Verb` attribute. Why aren't all of them documented? Additionally, what is the purpose of the `Verb`? They somewhat remind me of the `Phase` attribute of the old Processors, is this comparison valid?
7. When an error occurs and a `RetryStep` is defined, does it simply go to the referenced pipeline + step, retry, and continue where it left off (after the retry point), or does it execute everything again in between the retry point and the referenced ids in the retry point?

*- "technically speaking public APIs, but they are intentionally kept a bit under the radar, because they are considered “advanced” customizations (not expected to be needed for typical use cases)"